# Problemas al ejecutar este pequeño script, se ejecuta antes de cargado el DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

Buenas a todos, mi duda es la siguiente, tengo esta función que lo que pretende hacer es cambiar el tamaño de un desplegable, el caso es que cuando lo cargo no me funciona, me da cómo si se cargara antes de que el DOM estuviese completo o algo similar ya que me sale el mensaje de depuración "no hay una caja de selector", pero si ejecuto desde el inspector de elementos el script si que funciona y me cambia el tamaño. A que se debe esto? Muchas gracias a todos por adelantado.

```html
function cheqselector(){
var nodonuevoobj = document.getElementById('SelectedVariation0');
if (nodonuevoobj != null){
nodonuevoobj.style="min-width:300px";
console.log("hecho");
}
else{
 console.log("no hay una caja de selector");
}
}
window.onload = cheqselector();
```

Answer (score 4):

Deberias usar `DOMContentLoaded()` ya que este espera que se carguen todos los elementos del DOM, `window.onload` se ejecuta despues de cargar las imagenes asi como elementos padre generales y sub-frames

En cualquier caso es una buena practica incluirlo dentro de

```
(document).ready(function () { 
    cheqselector();
});
```

El motivo por el que te funciona desde el inspector es que el DOM ya esta cargado y reconoce al elemento con id `SelectedVariation0` mientras que con `window.onload` aun se esta construyendo

Comment: Habría que aclarar que estás usando jQuery en tu código. Sé que el evento `"DOMContentLoaded"` es parte del DOM, pero `element.ready` no lo es.

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload = cheqselector();`
y
`window.onload = cheqselector;`.
En el primero de los casos la función se ejecuta aún cuando los objetos no están cargados en el DOM ya que es invocada por `()`. Mientras que en el segundo de los casos la función es analizada como una expresión